# GNU screen locked, how to unlock?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

So here's what happened:

- I ssh to the server with a normal user
- I run `sudo -i`
- I run screen

Then I accidentally locked the screen session. to unlock it, it asks for root's password not the password of the normal user. The problem is I don't know the password of root. What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can attach to the session from "another terminal" (including another ssh connection).  That lets you recover anything that was in progress.
You can always kill the screen session as you started it, by using `sudo` to kill the parent process of the screen session (the one named "screen").

The feature only is useful if it is properly configured to begin with (usually that is not the case).

Further reading:

- [Disabling GNU Screen lock screen](https://www.pantz.org/software/screen/disabling_gnu_screen_lock_screen.html)
- [Can a locked gnu screen session terminal be accessed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9012/can-a-locked-gnu-screen-session-terminal-be-accessed)

Comment: I tried to detach it but it didn't work. does screen really allow you to detach once locked?